# Socket.io random chatroom

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to create an app(omegle like) where people can log in and talk to random people.
Case:When two people(clients) log in then console.log(room);  within the client (chat start event) prints the room.But when a third client logs in instead of waiting he creates a new room and connects with one of the other two creating a new room.This is not supposed to be happening based on my function findPeerForLoneSocket(socket);

Server side:

```
// Socket.io Setup
var io = socket(server);
var allUsers = {};  
var rooms = {};
var queue = [];
var names =[];

 app.get('/chat2',function(req,res){
   if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.render('chat');
    var findPeerForLoneSocket = function(socket) {
      if (queue.length > 0) {
          var peer= queue.pop();
          var room = socket.id + '#' + peer.id;
          peer.join(room);
          socket.join(room);
          rooms[peer.id] = room;
          rooms[socket.id] = room;
          peer.emit('chat start', {'name': names[socket.id], 'room':room});
          socket.emit('chat start', {'name': names[peer.id], 'room':room});
      } else {
          queue.push(socket);
      }
    }

    io.on('connection', function(socket) {      
      findPeerForLoneSocket(socket);
    });

} else {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
})
```

Client side:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
  var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
  var connected = false;
 var message = document.getElementById('message'),


handle = document.getElementById('handle'),
  btn = document.getElementById('send'),
  btn2 = document.getElementById('next'),
  output = document.getElementById('output');

  socket.on('connect', function (data) {
    connected = true;
  });

  socket.on('chat start', function(data) {
    $( "#connecting" ).remove();
    $( "#connected" ).text('Connected...');
      room = data.room;
      console.log(room);   
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a client connects to `/chat2` two things happen:
1. we render a `chat` file,
2. we create a new listener on `'connecting'` event.

So every time a new client connects the new listener is created. When two clients are already connected and are succesfully moved to a room we have already two listeners `io.on('connection')` waiting. When a third client connects, the first listener pushes him to the queue array and then the second listener pops him and creates a new room for him and for their peer. Both `socket.id` and `peer.id` are the same so the third client chats with themselves. 
And when the fourth clients connects there are three listeners already...

You have to take `io.on('connecting')` out of `app.get` code like in the below example (several console.logs added for debugging).

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

var queue = [];

var findPeerForLoneSocket = function(socket) {
    if (queue.length > 0) {
        var peer= queue.pop();
        console.log(peer.id + ' was popped from queue\n');
        log(queue);
        var room = socket.id + '#' + peer.id;
        peer.join(room);
        socket.join(room);
        console.log(socket.id + ' and ' + peer.id + ' joined room ' + room);
        peer.emit('chat start', {'name': socket.id, 'room':room});
        socket.emit('chat start', {'name': peer.id, 'room':room});
    } else {
        queue.push(socket);
        console.log(socket.id + ' was pushed to queue\n');
        log(queue);
    }
};

var log = arr => {
    console.log('Queue: ');
    for (let i = arr.length; i--;) {
        console.log(arr[i].id);
    }
    console.log('\n');
};

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log(socket.id + ' connected');
    findPeerForLoneSocket(socket);
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('express + socket.io server listening on *:3000');
});

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/sterg.html');
});
```